# Using Google+ with a Google Apps Account

Tags: google-workspace, google-plus

Why does Google not allow Google Apps Users to use Google+ without administrator approval?

This is the message we get:

> Google+ is not available for your organisation (vit.ac.in). Please contact your administrator to enable this service.
>   If you're an administrator, learn more here.

![Google+ is not available for your organisation (vit.ac.in). Please contact your administrator to enable this service.
If you're an administrator, learn more here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3GVx.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google apps is organization based service. Everything you do there is controlled and maintained by an organization. As Google+ is a social service, and social communication with an organization account is usually much more restricted than anything else(due to the fact that you get to share information with people outside the organization), using of Google+ by google apps users needs administrator approval.

You can go through the related [considerations](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1689647) of an organization before they turn on Google+ service.

For the same reason, when you are creating a document using Google drive with your Google apps account and share it with someone who doesn't have an account of your organization, Google will alert you, asking if you are sure you want to share information with someone outside the organization.